# Regex - string contains after certain character

Tags: regex

My use case is "www.example.com/myimage.jpg".

I need a regex to check that after the last occurrence of "/", the string contains a "."

Have tried this but it doesn't work for the "." check

```
/([^\/]+$)[^.]/
```

Comment: How could you possibly expect that to work? There can't be anything after `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]*$
```

This should work.

What this regex is doing is finding a \ character, then trying to find a string with a dot in it until you reach the end of the input. The trick is to not find anymore \ characters using [^/]. Which will match any character except \

This way we make sure this is the last \ character

Comment: Now explain why it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the pattern matching the last occurrence of `/` and then match a dot between all characters except `/` until the end of the string.

Note that `[^\/]` can also match a newline, and if you don't want to match a newline you could write it as `[^\/\r\n]`

If the delimiter is different than a forward slash you don't have to escape it.

```php
^.*\/[^\/\n.]*\.[^\/\n]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\/` Match `/`
- `[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*` Match a dot between optional chars other than `/` or `.`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8bj9gp/1)

Comment: You might even consider `^.*\/[^\/.]*\.[^\/]*$`, which would be a slight improvement I would think. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/heXk1S/1).

Comment: @Booboo You are right, it prevent backtracking over the dot. Thanks!